# Simplify string splitting

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am getting a result like this "PR242714031213" from a SQL query. This is basically a string PR + ssmmHHddMMyy. I need to extract and format it to a simple date ddMMyyyy.
I am using the following snippet with substrings which is working:

```
 string rawDate =  (string)lastProjaddedDate.ExecuteScalar();
             string year= rawDate.Substring(12,2);
             string month=rawDate.Substring(10,2);
             string day=rawDate.Substring(8,2);
             string date = day + "/" + month + "/" +"20"+ year;
             Label4.Text =date;
```

I am wondering if I can simplify the code to get the ddMMyyyy out of it.

PS: I know I need to change the way it is codified in the DB to avoid problems in few decades but lets start to simplify it.

Comment: Sigh. That's a broken database schema design. Anything dates should be a in a date column

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, happens when you work on some else code to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
Step - 1: Strip `PR` from the string
Step - 2: Parse to .Net `DateTime` object
Step - 3: Format to required format
```

Code :

```
string rawDate = "PR242714031213";
rawDate = rawDate.Substring(2);
DateTime dt;

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(rawDate, 
                           "ssmmHHddMMyy", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, 
                           out dt))
{
    //invalid date
}

string formattedDate = dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

In one statement it would be:

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2),
                            "ssmmHHddMMyy",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                            .ToString("ddMMyyy");
```

Comment: Upvoted because using `DateTime.TryParseExact` also means you benefit from date validation (e.g. ensuring you won't get the 30th of February).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you update the way dates are stored in the DB all you need is:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2), "ssmmHHddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

Otherwise use the following for the time being:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate.Substring(2), "ssmmHHddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

In any case you can choose whatever format you wish in the `ToString()` method.

Comment: Jurgen, the millennium and the centuries are not in the query result. So I cannot do that.

Comment: Edited it for your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression will give you terse code with validation as a bonus:

```
var match = Regex.Match(rawDate, @"PR\d{6}(?<d>\d\d)(?<m>\d\d)(?<y>\d\d)");
string date = match.Groups["d"].Value + "/" + match.Groups["m"].Value + "/20" + match.Groups["y"].Value;
```